# Switch Firebase Function to Gen-2

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i just saw that we have Cloud Functions 2nd generation which looks great: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview

But how can i switch my 1nd gen function to be 2nd gen? I see that i can [create a new function as 2nd gen like this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/console-quickstart):

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
 res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});
```

but what about old functions? Is there a way or i will have to delete and re-create them one-by-one?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking for.  Some tool or set of instructions to perform a source level conversion?  Also, you mentioned Firebase in the title, but everything you link to is for Cloud.  Firebase has a different set of tools to work with the same underlying product (Cloud Functions).

Comment: @DougStevenson ah you mean we have no access to Functions 2nd gen from firebase ?

Comment: What you see in the documentation is what you have available.

Comment: Today I deployed the same function to two different Firebase Projects and in one it got the "1st gen" logo but the other got "2nd gen" and later in the day the "2nd gen" turned back into "1st gen".  I'm referring to the blue pill-shaped logo seen if you go to console.firebase.google.com > click project > Functions > click 3 vertical dots > Detailed usage stats (takes you to Cloud Functions UI).

Comment: I noticed there was a parameter on the URL called `env=gen1` which when I change manually to `env=gen2`, it changes the blue pill-shaped logo from "1st gen" to "2nd gen".  Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cloud Function Gen2 is only available for the product Cloud Functions, not Firebase functions.
Firebase functions use the library `firebase-functions` while Cloud Functions uses `@google-cloud/functions-framework`.
From the Google Cloud console both functions will appear the same but if you try to deploy a Cloud Function gen2 over a Cloud Function gen1, you will receive the following error:

`Failed to create function, function projects/[PROJECT_NUMBER]/locations/[LOCATION]/functions/[FUNCTION_NAME] already exists under 'Gen 1' environment. Please delete conflicting function first or deploy the function with a different name.`

You will need to migrate completely from Firebase functions to brand-new created Cloud Functions gen2.

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to change this? We could really use the gen 2 features.

Comment: @NickJ, not sure when it switched over but looks like Gen2 is now supported (in preview) for Firebase Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta

Answer (score 7):

Things may have changed as of August 9, 2022 when [Cloud Functions 2nd Gen become Generally Available](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-2nd-generation-now-generally-available), so I'll document what worked for me in a TypeScript project.

### 1st Gen

#### Client

"firebase": "9.9.3"

```
import { httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { AddTwoNumbersInputParams, AddTwoNumbersInputResult } from "./util/shared/my-types";

// ...

const addTwoNumbersFuncCallable = httpsCallable<AddTwoNumbersInputParams, AddTwoNumbersInputResult>(
    firebaseFunctions,
    "addTwoNumbersFunc",
);

const result = await addTwoNumbersFuncCallable({
    firstNum: 3,
    secondNum: 5
});

console.log("Result", result.data);
```

#### Server

"firebase-functions": "^3.21.0"

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { AddTwoNumbersInputParams, AddTwoNumbersInputResult } from "./util/shared/my-types";

// ...

export const addTwoNumbersFunc = functions.https.runWith({ memory: "1GB" }).onCall((params: AddTwoNumbersInputParams, ctx): AddTwoNumbersInputResult => {
    
    if (!ctx.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "You must be logged in to call server-side functions");
    }


    return { result: params.firstNum + params.secondNum };
}
```

#### Shared

To share the TypeScript interfaces AddTwoNumbersInputParams and AddTwoNumbersInputResult across my client and server code, I created a symlink to a directory `util/shared` containing the following definitions in a file called my-types.ts:

```
export interface AddTwoNumbersInputParams {
    firstNum: number
    secondNum: number
}

export interface AddTwoNumbersInputResult {
    result: number
}
```

### 2nd Gen

#### Client

"firebase": "9.9.3"

```
import { httpsCallableFromURL } from "firebase/functions"; // see note1, note2, note3 below 

// ...

const addTwoNumbersFuncCallable = httpsCallableFromURL<AddTwoNumbersInputParams, AddTwoNumbersInputResult>(
    firebaseFunctions,
    "https://addtwonumbersfunc-fri67ycgta-uc.a.run.app",  // see note1, note2, note3 below 
);

const result = await addTwoNumbersFuncCallable({
    firstNum: 3,
    secondNum: 5
});

console.log("Result", result.data);
```

note1: The [callable documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/callable) and [http-events documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/http-events#invoke_an_http_function) both say that the `firebase deploy` command should output the URL but I did not see it.  I obtained it instead by going here:

1. [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Click your project
3. Click Functions (in Table of Contents on left-hand-side but click "All products" if you don't see it and then click Functions)
4. Copy the URL for your function in the Trigger column; it should be of the form `https://<lowercase_func_name>-<random-hash>-<region>.a.run.app`

note2: At first I was worried 2nd Gen functions would introduce a manual step into my Continuous Integration pipeline because they output a URL now (or so [it said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/callable)).  With several Firebase projects representing different stages to promote to production ([Google's recommendation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments)), I thought I would have a new hassle to copy and paste the URL for each deployment of the 2nd Gen Functions.  Luckily it's not as bad as I thought because ["the URL remains stable after deployment"](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#coming_soon_in_2nd_gen).  So I only had to deploy once to get the URL, plug it into my client code, and then it remained the same for each deployment thereafter.  That said, it's still a different URL for each of my Firebase Projects.  So I will have to do more work to promote to production.  But maybe they'll fix this because they said ["In a future release, 2nd gen function URLs will be updated to be both stable and deterministic."](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#coming_soon_in_2nd_gen).

note3: I found the URL thing so combersome that I tried without it and had success with the Firebase Functions emulator but not on a real Firebase Project.  With the emulator, I was litterally able to continue using the `httpsCallable()` function that accepts a name of the function instead of the `httpsCallableFromURL()` function that requires a URL.  It worked on the emulator, but not with a real Firebase Project.

#### Server

"firebase-functions": "^3.21.0"

```
import * as functionsV2 from "firebase-functions/v2";
import {CallableRequest} from "firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https";
import {HttpsOptions} from "firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/https";

// ... 

const httpsOptions: HttpsOptions = {
    memory: "16GiB"  // see note4 below
};


// see note5 below
export const addtwonumbersfunc = functionsV2.https.onCall(httpsOptions, (request: CallableRequest<AddTwoNumbersInputParams>): AddTwoNumbersInputResult => {
    if (!request.auth) {
        throw new functionsV2.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "You must be logged in to call server-side functions");
    }

    return { result: request.data.firstNum + request.data.secondNum };
});
```

note4: The [`runWith()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) syntax for setting the memory (etc.) seems to have changed to an [`HttpsOptions` object that you pass to the `onCall()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/manage-functions) that accepts `HttpsOptions` such as `memory`.  One of the exciting things about 2nd Gen is it offers [higher memory allocations than 1st Gen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/manage-functions#override-CPU) so I have demonstrated that here but increasing from "1GB" to "16GiB" (note also the change from "GB" to "GiB").

note5: ["Function names are restricted to lowercase letters, numbers, and dashes."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta#other_limitations) but hopefully coming soon is ["Support for using capital letters in function names."](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#coming_soon_in_2nd_gen)

#### Shared

No changes required

Comment: This is extremely helpful information. I was looking how to invoke the new cloud-run based functions!

Comment: Thank you, Michael! One update: `httpsCallableFromURL` isn't needed for 2nd gen functions any more. We've updated the docs to use `httpsCallable` instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#call_the_function

Answer (score 4):

There is now an [**upgrade guide**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade) that describes how to migrate to 2nd gen. You'll see full detail in the guide, but a rough outline is:

1. Update the imports and trigger definitions in your code
2. If you were using `functions.config`, move to [parameterized configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#params)
3. Migrate traffic to the new 2nd gen functions

Also note that functions can be migrated one by one, so you don't have to do it all at once:

> 1st gen and 2nd gen functions can coexist side-by-side in the same file. This allows for easy migration piece by piece, as you're ready. We recommend migrating one function at a time, performing testing and verification before proceeding.
>
> - [The migration process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#the_migration_process)

Comment: Jeff, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)